# how to compile proto file in Java

Tags: java, build, protocol-buffers

i want build my .proto file. but, it say " File not found."
Is my command wrong?

- java 17
- macOS

  protoc --proto_path=src/main/proto/read/excel_read.proto --java_out=src/main/java/com/study/grpc/service src/main/proto/read/excel_read.proto

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvSLI.png)

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

package proto.read.excel_read;

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.study.grpc.service";
option java_outer_classname = "ExcelReadServiceProto";

service ExcelReadService {
  rpc getMallExcel(GetExcelRequest) returns (GetMallExcelResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/excel/mall/{excel_seq}"
    };
   };
 }
```

I also downloaded protoc.

Comment: Note, regardless of your eventual resolution, that (1) it is customary to use a Maven or Gradle plugin to execute `protoc` for you, and (2) it is customary to put the generated source code in `target/generated-sources` instead of `src/main`.

Comment: I see a few problems. First, proto_path should be a directory root like used with `-I`; it is used as a root searching for imports. So it should instead by `--proto_path=src/main/proto`. However, that directory probably doesn't include annotations.proto, so you'd still get failures. I would also recommend using the Maven and Gradle plugins as they can discover annotations.proto from the protobuf-java dependency itself. I'll also note `target/generated-sources` is used by the plugin, not as a source location.